# open csv file in python to customize dictionary

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I would like to know to load this csv file:

```
Epitope,ID,Frequency,Assay

AVNIVGYSNAQGVDY,123431,27.0,Tetramer

DIKYTWNVPKI,887473,50.0,3H

LRQMRTVTPIRMQGG,34234,11.9,Elispot
```

into a python dictionary like this:

```
d = {'AVNIVGYSNAQGVDY': [ID[123431],Frequency[27.0],Assay['Tetramer']], 'DIKYTWNVPKI': [ID[887473],Frequency[50.0],Assay['3H']], 'LRQMRTVTPIRMQGG': [ID[34234],Frequency[11.9],Assay['Elispot']]}
```

I am working with lists since my actual file is bigger and I will append more values to those lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do you know about the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module? If not, read the introduction and examples to the point where you know how to get an iterable of rows. Print each one out, and they'll look something like this:

```
['AVNIVGYSNAQGVDY', '123431', '27.0', 'Tetramer']
```

Or, if you use a `DictReader`:

```
{'Epitope': 'AVNIVGYSNAQGVDY', 'ID': '123431', 
 'Frequency': '27.0', 'Assay': 'Tetramer'}
```

But you don't want a list of lists, or a list of dictionaries; you want a dictionary of lists, where each key is the `Epitope` from a row, and the corresponding value is the other three values, right? So… just insert each row into a dictionary that way:

```
d = {}
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    with csv.DictReader(f) as reader:
        for row in reader:
            d[row['Epitope']] = [row['ID'], row['Frequency'], row['Assay']]
```

(This would be more compact with a plain `reader` instead of a `DictReader`, but I think it's more readable this way if you come back to the code a few months from now.)

You also want to convert the values and use them as keys for another lookup, but that should be trivial. For example:

```
            row_id = ID[int(row['ID'])]
            row_frequency = Frequency[float(row['Frequency'])]
            row_assay = Assay[row['Assay']]
            d[row['Epitope']] = [row_id, row_frequency, row_assay]
```

You can clean this up a bit by writing the row transformation as a function, and then just using a dictionary comprehension:

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    with csv.DictReader(f) as reader:
        d = {row['Epitope']: process_row(row) for row in reader}
```